# FlatList - Fetching Data From Postman Localhost url

Tags: javascript, react-native

- ****Hi Everyone,
  I'm very beginner to this platform.
  Could any one help me to where i did mistake in the following code?

  i'm Using SQL server for database
  In App.js I have tried the below code...****

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      ActivityIndicator,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,
      Dimensions,
      FlatList
    } from 'react-native';


    export default class App extends React.Component {
      //Set States
      constructor(props)
      {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: []
    }
  }
  //Get Data From API
  componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('http://localhost:7483/api/StudentData/')
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      this.state({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      })
    })
  }

  _renderItem=({item,index}) => {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  render()
  {
    let {container}=styles
    let {dataSource,isLoading}=this.state
    //Use FlatList for Display Data
    return(
      <View style={container}>
        <FlatList
          data={dataSource}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  } 
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  welcome:{
    fontSize:20,
    textAlign:'center',
    margin:10
  } 
});
```

[I'm getting data in postman url from SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW8Rz.png)

[I'm getting this warning msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMHyG.png)

[Empty Emulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4vHk.png)

[Console Warning msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zEvH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add you IP address instead of `localhost`

1.) Run `cmd`

2.) type `ipconfig`

3.) Scroll Down to `IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.**.**`

4.) Copy this IP and replace it in place of `localhost`

5.) Done

Get your IP like this

[image]

So Suppose if your IPv4 address is - 192.168.100.84 then

Your `fetch` should look like this

```
fetch('http://192.168.100.84:7483/api/StudentData/')
```

**Also for setting state after `fetch`**

You have to do like this

```
this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: responseJson })
```

Instead of this

```
this.state({ isLoading: false, dataSource: responseJson })
```

In your `render` part write like this

```
 return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Your `App.js` using Function Component

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [State, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    dataSource: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    GetData();
  }, []);

  const GetData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch('http://192.168.43.159:7483/api/StudentData/');
    const response = await result.json();
    setState({
      ...State,
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: response,
    });
  };

  const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={State.dataSource}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your guidance,


' //Get Data From API
  componentDidMount()
  {
    await fetch('http://192.168.43.159/api/StudentData/')
    .then((response)=> await response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      })      
    })
  }' 

I updated my code like above... but i got "Syntax error await" "Unexpected Reserved word await..." like this...

Comment: Also insert the port in which your SQL server is running...in your case I guess it is `7483`...So inside your `fetch` would look like this `'http://192.168.100.84:7483/api/StudentData/'`

Comment: i'm getting Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await' in the emulator

Comment: Don't have to use `await` I've updated the answer

Comment: Your Final Fetch statement will look like this..... `fetch('http://192.168.43.159:7483/api/StudentData/')`

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. but still i'm getting the same warning msg and nothing displaying in emulator. Emulator is blank screen as attached previous

Comment: Did you update the `state` changing line that I mentioned in the answer??

Comment: Yes I changed,

' componentDidMount()
  {
     fetch('http://192.168.43.159:7483/api/StudentData/')
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      })      
    })
  }'

Answer (score 0):

In the android emulator URL with **localhost** not working, so you must set ipv4 address instead of that.

Also change **this.state** -> **this.setState**

Comment: Hi thank you for your guidance, i'm getting Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: Is this error from the current component you shared that ?

Comment: This error when be happend you use 'await' without 'async' or use in the "fetch/then/catch" structure for getting data , check if you use that to wrong or not.

Comment: Yes, i gave fetch/then/catch structure... but still facing the same issue...